# Creating a dymo tape text effect without changing the markup?

Tags: css

So given that I have a paragraph element with text in it:

```
<p>Something something something</p>
```

What CSS witchcraft do I have to perform to have my text looking like this?

Given that I am pulling my content from a CMS, I'd have to do some working around that seems like more hassle than it's worth to achieve this effect. What are some approaches I could use to go about achieving this?

Edit: [Here is an example that uses manual line breaks at the end of every `span` to achieve this effect](http://svevoromano.it/css_tests/dymo_tape_effect_with_css/)

I can't use this because I don't have any say over when a line should break since all the text is pulled from the CMS

[image: Dyno tape text]

Comment: I don't think CSS can do this, but there is a font available.
http://www.dafont.com/search.php?psize=m&q=dymo

Comment: I sort of figured I am SOL. Thanks for that, do you know of anything similar with Open Sans text?

Comment: Doing this with Open Sans would mean using CSS to do this, which cannot be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I got pretty close. (http://jsfiddle.net/8vUJ2/)

HTML:

```
<div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean congue nunc ipsum, sed aliquam tortor adipiscing non. Vivamus vitae egestas ipsum. Integer sed congue elit, eu blandit nulla. Pellentesque fermentum turpis ante, id fringilla lectus posuere quis. Ut scelerisque non erat non congue. Suspendisse non semper lorem. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce molestie nec erat at cursus. Integer imperdiet tellus quis lacus dapibus egestas. Curabitur massa mi, vulputate quis augue vitae, accumsan tincidunt massa. Ut quis vestibulum turpis, eu ultricies ligula. Sed sed interdum odio. Quisque tristique lobortis dolor, id ornare nisi adipiscing faucibus. Sed fermentum dolor faucibus felis vulputate, et bibendum libero porta.</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    border-top:1px solid #6c5c5d;
    padding:7px 0 9px;
    line-height:34px;
    font-size:15px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #31221f, #030000);
    color:#c3bcb6;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #030000,  
        1px -1px 0 #030000,
        -1px 1px 0 #030000,
        1px 1px 0 #030000,
        0 0 4px #fff;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:courier;
    font-weight:bold;
}

div{
    padding-left:20px;
    background:url(http://i62.tinypic.com/nn8s41.png) 0 0 repeat-y;
}
```

I used an image:

[image]

on the left to make the line beginnings vary, and I had to use css background gradients, so support in older browsers won't be too good, but for a pure css solution I think it works. I also used `text-shadow` to gibe the font the sort of almost-outline effect you can see in the image you posted.

Comment: This was an exceptionally well written and researched answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
p{
    background: black;
    color:white;
    display:inline;
    font-family: courier;
    padding:3px;
    line-height:2em; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHT63/3/

Comment: This is pretty dope! And is pretty much what I was trying to achieve. Line beginnings and endings are very close to the edge, is there any way to give this more space?